# How to have my PCs uncover a mole in the city guard

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, investigation

So I want to create a situation for the players where they have to figure out who, within the city guard, is secretly working for a certain necromancy cult based in the local swamp.

I was initially going to introduce the problem through either the Guard Captain or his second-in-command, and then eventually have the second-in-command turn out to be the mole...or someone else, not too sure yet.

I was planning on giving the a few suspects that they would have to investigate who would eventually end up being red herrings or dead ends...or maybe give em clues on other suspects or the second-in-command. I had some ideas like:

1. Guard A - Came back alone from an expedition into the swamp
2. Guard B - No one knows what he does after work, lives alone
3. Guard C - Overall shady guy, but when interrogated has some information that the second-in-command might be the mole?
4. Some more...

I was wondering what are some good ways to make this whole situation more enjoyable or engaging for the players? I have and idea for the mole and some red herrings, but nothing is really fleshed out as of now.

Comment: This is a cool question but would be a poor fit for the site's format. You should try a forum, instead, [here's a list we recommend.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23064)

Comment: [This article on the three clue rule](http://thealexandrian.net/wordpress/1118/roleplaying-games/three-clue-rule) might answer your question.